# CircleCi node specified version image is different than in practice

Tags: node.js, docker, circleci

i have the config.yaml file that specify

```
docker:
      - image: circleci/node:9.10.1
```

But when connecting with ssh to the container the and running the command:

```
node -v
```

it returns 4.2.6.

The container is running on UBUNTU 14.
Is there something im missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the extension of the config file.
App apparently CircleCi version 2 doesnt work good with .YAML files.

So the solution was to change from config.YAML to config.YML

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Running `docker run -it circleci/node:9.10.1 node -v` on your local computer will show you the expected version.

If you're indeed using that image in CircleCI 2.0, it would not be running Ubuntu 14.04 and that images is based on Debian. Something you're doing or that is happening in incorrect. I'd suggest posting in CircleCI Discuss with more info (such as a link or your config) to have an employee or community member to take a look and help out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I indeed talked with tech support. The version of node was correct, this version is running on Ubuntu as well.